# gcc error when I'm trying to install readline-6.2

Tags: python, gcc, centos

Could anyone kindly help me out what's wrong with the gcc when I am trying to install readline module for my newly installed python2.7 in the CentOS server?

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC     -DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -    DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -    DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c     Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o -Wno-strict-prototypes
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a     readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/readline.so
gcc: readline/libreadline.a: No such file or directory
gcc: readline/libhistory.a: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Quick guess is that you don't have GNU Readline installed. Try `rpm -i readline`.

Comment: Is this a readline source package or is this default readline package?  In the latter case, have you readline-devel installed? What version CentOS version are you using?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

readline is bundled with the Python module and it attempts to build it for you, but you'll see this error display if your system was unable to complete the build. In my case, `patch` was missing from the system. `yum install patch` solved it for me.

Comment: Until I came to the patch package, I also installed, ncurses-devel and readline-devel as well. With all 3 it worked.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue on CentOS 7. `yum install patch` followed by `pip install readline` and it works right away.

Comment: on CentOS yum install readline-devel did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

on Ubuntu 
`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev ncurses-dev`