# Bloomberg python api blpapi3.5.5 install error about missing blpapi_types.h

Tags: python, gcc, bloomberg

Attempting to install bloomberg python api blpapi3.5.5 results in this error:

> blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx:3110:26: fatal error: blpapi_types.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Full install log:

```
root@najeeb:/home/najeeb/Desktop/pyqt1/blpapi-3.5.5# python setup.py install

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'blpapi._internals' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -  fPIC -I/home/najeeb/Desktop/pyqt1/blpapi-3.5.5/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c   blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/blpapi/internals_wrap.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but   not for C++ [enabled by default]
blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx:3110:26: fatal error: blpapi_types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc error when I'm trying to install readline-6.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166277/gcc-error-when-im-trying-to-install-readline-6-2)

Comment: If you are a MacOS user. You can try this solution: [Link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40393577/3755348)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a MacOS user. Try to see the solution: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40393577/3755348).

I think you forgot to add the bellow lines:

```
# set environment variable
export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/sampathkumarm/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/Darwin/
```